What results in TextEncoder.encode() using a buffer of a given type?
The return value of TextEncoder.encode() is Uint8Array<ArrayBufferLike>. The ArrayBufferLike type includes ArrayBuffer and SharedArrayBuffer. How to know which type of array buffer encode() will use? Can it be configured? Why doesn't it just use ArrayBuffer?

In case of JS, MDN, and the standard both say it's an Uint8Array, the latter also saying there's an ArrayBuffer inside, and that encodeInto() allows shared buffer.

I don't think there's ever a case where an instance of TextEncoder can create a new Uint8Array that's backed by a SharedArrayBuffer — the buffer property on the typed array returned by the encoder's encode method will always be an instance of ArrayBuffer — the WHATWG encoding spec describes the last step of TextEncoder#encode this way:

If result is finished, then convert output into a byte sequence and return a Uint8Array object wrapping an ArrayBuffer containing output.


TypedArrays were only very recently made generic (in TS version 5.7 released about a month ago / original PR) — before that, all typed arrays exclusively used the ArrayBufferLike type for the backing binary storage and couldn't be typed more narrowly.
There are certainly cases where it's useful to have a SharedArrayBuffer — e.g. bring-your-own-buffer scenarios like the encodeInto method of a text encoder.
This is likely just an oversight in the DOM lib types (source) and can/will be narrowed in the future.
